# Map services disappear in Silverlight and Internet Explorer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, internet-explorer, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

I upgraded from Silverlight Viewer 3.0 to 3.2 and upgraded one of my projects.  Now in that project everything disappears at the last 2 zoom levels.  If I switch to dynamic instead of cached it displays.  But I tried recaching and it didn't help.  It will also display fine in Mozilla.  Any idea why IE (10 or 11) are behaving in this manner?

Comment: Need more info.  If you launch (f12) IE developer tools, what kind of errors and requests/responses are you getting?  Perhaps make use of licecap or Jing to embed a animated gif/video detailing more info about the problem

Comment: I don't see anything when I run developer tools.  The zoom has no effect on what is coming up in that dialog.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to successfully downgrade back to version 3.0.  It's lonely being the only one with a particular problem.